# Primes of the form $d^2+d+1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Is $d^2+d+1$ prime for infinitely many $d\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$?

This is expected by the [Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture) which says that, under some conditions, given a polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ we have $p(d)$ prime for infinitely many $d\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. Is there some proof of this when $p(x) = x^2+x+1$?

Comment: I think there is no polynomial of degree $\ge 2$ for which this is known to hold.

Comment: As mentioned in the section "Partial results: only Dirichlet's theorem" of the Wikipedia page you linked, this is only known for linear polynomials, and for no others.

Comment: At least you can prove that if $X$ is an integer greater that $1$ such that $p(X)$ is a prime number then $X \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ or $X \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$: in other words, the polynomial does produce infinitely many composite numbers.

Comment: @JoséHdz.Stgo. This is true for every polynomial though, so it is not a special property of this one. This is for example shown in the answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86018/proving-a-polynomial-fx-composite-for-infinitely-many-x.

Comment: In the given context it's good to recall https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedlander%E2%80%93Iwaniec_theorem.

Comment: I am afraid that it is not even known whether a polynomial of degree more than 1 for which it holds exists

Comment: It might be interesting to restrict oneself to the case where $d$ is itself prime and study the images of the iterates of $f:x\mapsto x^2+x+1$, for example trying to establish that for infinitely many primes $p$, there exists an integer $k_{p}$ such that $f^{\circ k_{p}}(p)$ is prime.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN Wouldn't that immediately imply this specific case of Bunyanakovsky?

Comment: I guess so, that's the goal actually. An approach through dynamic systems might be fruitful. I have the vague idea that this could be related to hypothetical "n-th roots of automorphisms" i.e. maps $g$ such that $g^{\circ n}$ is an automorphism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer the question and summarizing the comments: the answer is no, there is no known proof of this conjecture.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This is surprising to me :)

Comment: For the closely related question of whether there are infinitely many primes of the form $d^2+1$, see the Wikipedia article on [Landau's problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_problems#Near-square_primes) for some references.

Comment: @number yes as a non-number theorist it is indeed surprising that such a basic statement is not known. However number theorists know that we know embarrassingly little about many things, so wouldn’t be surprised that we don’t know this.

Comment: I think DHR sieve can help to prove that the number of the positive integers $n\le$ such that $n^2+n+1$ is prime is at least $c\cdot\dfrac{n}{log(n)log(log(n))}$ for some positive constant $c$ and therefore that sum of their reciprocal diverges at least as fast as $log(log(log(n)))$, and that the similar results hold for any other irreducible quadratic polynomial.